# Connecting with a Java client to SharePoint with NTLMv2

Tags: http-module, ntlm

I am using MAC and LINUX, Java6 and Apache http-client 3.1 to connect to SharePoint with NTLM auth.

I connect to ntlm using http://jcifs.samba.org/ and it worked fine until I had to connect to NTLMv2. I tried this http://devsac.blogspot.com/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html but it doesnt work for me with NTLMv2,

Is there any way to make my httpclient 3.1 connect to SharePoint NTLMv2 ? if not, is there a way to connect java to sharepoint NTLMv2 without httpclient?

By the way, I make sure the SharePoint side is using NTLMv2 by checking the "require NTLMv2 session security" checkbox, according to http://www.websense.com/support/article/kbarticle/How-do-I-Check-NTLM-Version-for-XID-Compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You can try connecting to Sharepoint through Burp proxy (http://www.portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)
which enables you to use NTLM v1/v2 authentication.